# How can I populate an in-cell dropdown list based on table values?

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I am trying to create a dynamic in-cell dropdown list using VBA. Currently I have the dropdown list populated based on the values I have inputted. However, as I foresee the use for this program growing, I would like to make the dropdown list dynamic. Is there a way to have VBA loop through a table and populate the dropdown list based on values in column 1 (for example)?

Below is the code I currently have; as you can see, the formula values are static based on the values I've hard-coded in:

```
Sub Dropdown_Setup()
'Setup appropriate template dropdowns on 'template' sheet

    Set wB = ThisWorkbook
    Set tempSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

'Populate 'machine' dropdown
    With tempSht.Range("$B$15").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:="H1 - EOS M280, H2 - SLM, H4 - CL M2, H5 - EOS M400, H6 - SLM 2.0"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through each cell in the first column of your listobject, and build a comma separated string that can be assigned to `Formula1` for validation.

I've assumed that Sheet2 contains your listobject, and that the listobject is named Table1.  Change these names accordingly.

Also, you've defined `wB`, however you haven't used it in your code.  Since it's not really necessary, I removed it.

```
Sub Dropdown_Setup()
'Setup appropriate template dropdowns on 'template' sheet

'Set the source table
    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Set sourceTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")

'Get the items from the first column of the source table
    Dim itemsList As String
    Dim currentCell As Range
    itemsList = ""
    For Each currentCell In sourceTable.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
        If Len(currentCell.Value) > 0 Then
            itemsList = itemsList & "," & currentCell.Value
        End If
    Next currentCell
    itemsList = Mid(itemsList, 2)

'Set the template sheet
    Dim tempSht As Worksheet
    Set tempSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")

'Populate 'machine' dropdown
    With tempSht.Range("$B$15").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add _
            Type:=xlValidateList, _
            AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:=itemsList
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

End Sub
```